# How to : Populate Content of Page to another page in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop, hook-wordpress

I am using OptionTree for WordPress option panel, I am getting the page ID, and using that page ID I want to populate the content of the page to another page.   Here is my code:

```
<?php 
$test_input = ot_get_option( 'for_myapp_features' );
?>
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'page_id=$test_input' ); ?>
<?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post();  ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

Any help would be helpful.

Comment: have you tried this? `echo get_post_field('post_content', $test_input);`

Comment: @RaunakGupta Yes thanks, getting the content, just let me know how to get title too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can use [`get_post_field`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_field) and [`get_the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/) to get
>   content and title.

```
$test_input = ot_get_option('for_myapp_features');

echo get_post_field('post_title', $test_input); // to get the title
//or
//echo get_the_title($test_input); // to get the title
echo get_post_field('post_content', $test_input); //to get the content
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the content for that page, then add  `the_content()` within your while loop. `the_content()` will display the page’s content. I would  also add a query reset, `wp_reset_query();`, after the endwhile to restores the global post data to the original query.